# Why is my LDAP authentication/url not working?

Tags: ldap, apache2

I am configuring Apache2 to require valid LDAP credentials for a specific resource. I have for example the following `AuthnProviderAlias`

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap users>
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.devops.ok/dc=devops,dc=ok?uid?sub?(&(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(isMemberOf=cn=users,dc=groups,dc=devops,dc=ok))"
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=admin"
AuthLDAPBindPassword ****
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

Basic authentication is configured, there is a prompt for credentials but users cannot get in. Apache reports internal server 500 response code.

When I add `LogLevel debug` log shows that user is not valid

```
[Thu Sep 01 08:57:37.878815 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3501] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.0.2.2:34163] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Thu Sep 01 08:57:37.878887 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3501] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.0.2.2:34163] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
```

My suspicion is that `AuthLDAPURL` is not correct.

How can I check if this URL is correct? The URL is simple now but it will be more complex. Is there a better way coming up with a valid URL other than trial and error, reloading Apache service? What tools can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that cn=admin is the issue. 
Is that the Fully Distinguished name of the admin user?

"no authenticated user yet" implies the LDAP server implementation is not accepting the bind request.

Try the connection with a KNOW good LDAP browser. (We like [APache Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/))

Comment: I used LDAP browser feature in Eclipse which I think is more or less the same as Apache Studio. This allows me to build LDAP url easily using filter editor.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the ldapsearch utility to check to ensure you can successfully bind search using the filter.

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.devops.ok -b dc=devops,dc=ok -D "cn=Admin" -w yourpassword "(&(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(isMemberOf=cn=users,dc=groups,dc=devops,dc=ok))" uid
```

Also like jwilleke suggests double check your BindDN to ensure it's correct.

It's not good security practice to use your "cn=Admin"  or  "cn=Directory Manager" (your admin accounts for your Directory Server) to bind to a directory server.   Create an unprivileged service account to perform these tasks.